# Issue with an active div on a one page website

Tags: jquery, css

I'm creating my first one page website.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dgfhjxLt/

When you scroll through the pages, the link colours should change to show the user they're on that page, so far this works fine, the issue is with the first div.

When you first go on the site, the first link should show active i.e. text should be blue, this does not happen until you scroll a little first then it works fine.

Been stuck on the for an hour, surly it's a simple fix?

Here's the jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   
var offsetHeader = 60;

$('.scroll').click(function(){
    var $target = $($(this).attr('href'));
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    $('body').stop().scrollTo( $target , 800, {'axis':'y', offset: -offsetHeader});
    return false;
});

/**
     * This part handles the highlighting functionality.
     * We use the scroll functionality again, some array creation and 
     * manipulation, class adding and class removing, and conditional testing
     */
    var aChildren = $("nav li").children(); // find the a children of the list items
    var aArray = []; // create the empty aArray
    for (var i=0; i < aChildren.length; i++) {    
        var aChild = aChildren[i];
        var ahref = $(aChild).attr('href');
        aArray.push(ahref);
    } // this for loop fills the aArray with attribute href values

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop(); // get the offset of the window from the top of page
        var windowHeight = $(window).height(); // get the height of the window
        var docHeight = $(document).height();

        for (var i=0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
            var theID = aArray[i];
            var divPos = $(theID).offset().top-60; // get the offset of the div from the top of page
            var divHeight = $(theID).height(); // get the height of the div in question
            if (windowPos >= divPos && windowPos < (divPos + divHeight)) {
                $("a[href='" + theID + "']").addClass("active");
            } else {
                $("a[href='" + theID + "']").removeClass("active");
            }
        }

        if(windowPos + windowHeight == docHeight) {
            if (!$("nav li:last-child a").hasClass("nav-active")) {
                var navActiveCurrent = $(".nav-active").attr("href");
                $("a[href='" + navActiveCurrent + "']").removeClass("nav-active");
                $("nav li:last-child a").addClass("nav-active");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: when the site opens will it always start from the top ? if so you can simply use css!

Comment: no, if you refresh the page it will start from where it was which could be half way down the page

Comment: Your initial `active` class should be on the `<a>` tag and not on the `<li>`.

Comment: i see moving active classes solves the problem for first load but if the page starts from 2nd link ... you will have to play with jQuery!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jQuery is using `active` class on anchor but you have used active class on `li` on first element simply move it to anchor tag like this:

```
<li><a class="scroll active" href="#test1">test1</a></li>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dgfhjxLt/2/)**